# Locating accuracy of Azure Spatial Anchors and Unity World Anchor

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, azure-spatial-anchors

I've trying use spatial anchors for my Hololens app, that persists holograms across app sessions.
My app does't run on android or ios: runs only on Hololens, also does not share anchors among other devices.

I think that it is enough to save Unity World Anchor to local storage for this usage.

But, I only concern about locating accuracy.
Does differ locating accuracy between Azure Spatial Anchors and Unity World Anchor?

Answer (score 2):

No. That is actually the same anchor, implemented in Windows Holographic.